# JavaScript onclick Function Check All Checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I have this JS script that checks all checkboxes but in a bookmark link:

```
javascript:[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'),function(el){el.checked=true});
```

Now how to translate it to:

```
<a href="#" onclick="...">Check all</a>
```

I want it as a simple link not a master checkbox that toggles them all.

Thanks.

Comment: so did you try to put the code into the onclick?

Comment: `<a href="javascript:[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=\"checkbox\"]'),function(el){el.checked=true});">Check all</a>`

Comment: also, not sure why the code is not just `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(...)`

Comment: @epascarello Because `NodeList` is not an `Array` and does not have `forEach()` in every browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just copy that code into the `href`attribute, but it's a bit nicer to make a function for it instead, so you don't have JS code laying around in your markup:

```js
function check() {
  document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(e => e.checked = true);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">

<a href="javascript:check()">Check all</a>
```

This however requires the browser to support `forEach` on a node list, and also arrow expressions. For better compatibility, use your code inside the function instead:

```js
function check() {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'), function (el) {
    el.checked = true;
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">

<a href="javascript:check()">Check all</a>
```

Comment: `NodeList` is not an `Array` and does not have `forEach()` in every browser. Also not every browser supports arrow functions.

Comment: @connexo I have added that information to the answer if more compatibility is required, thanks.